# Kendo Autocomplete with server filtering in Angular, how to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, autocomplete

I followed this example which describes basic working with Kendo Autocomplete in AngularJS.

Problem is that example works only with local defined data.

Could somebody post example how to work with remote JSON data source?

Link is:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/angular

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

Just use $http, so something like this:

```
angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ]);
function MyCtrl($scope, $http){

$http.get('/remoteDataSource').
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.countryNames = data;
    });
}
```

If the data is changing as you type, you could use a $watch also:

```
angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ]);
function MyCtrl($scope, $http){

$scope.$watch('textboxValue', function(){
    $http.get('/remoteDataSource/' + $scope.textboxValue).
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.countryNames = data;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: But $scope.countryNames should be refreshed after each char which user type in.

Comment: I can't see why this wouldn't be the case with the above code.

Comment: Because of the applied filter in the remote searching by given string value from input.

Answer (score 0):

in html just use

```
<input kendo-auto-complete  
        k-data-text-field="'ProductName'"
        k-data-value-field="'ProductID'"
        k-data-source="productsDataSource" />
```

in Js use

```
angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ])
  .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
      $scope.productsDataSource = {
        type: "JSON",
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products",
            }
        }
    };


  })
```