# How to call controller action method in kendo control angularJS code?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, autocomplete, kendo-ui

I am using this autocomplete with angularJs code.

I am new in angularJS code and I am familer with Kendo Js code with MVC.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/angular

But in there countries are static but i want to get records from database like call controller action method from this angularJs code.

If possible then please share detail like which type of data i need to return from action method like array, json or other?

Thanks,
Jatin

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800377/kendo-autocomplete-with-server-filtering-in-angular-how-to

Answer (score 0):

You must define your own DataSource, which use factory as a data provider. Read more about this topics.

```
<input kendo-auto-complete ng-model="country" k-data-source="countryNames"  style="width: 400px" />

$scope.countryNames = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function (options) {
            return  DataFactory.getData(options)

        }
    }
});

factory('DataFactory', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    return {
      getData: function(options) {
        return $http.get('data.json').success(
          function(results) {
            options.success(results);
          });

      }
    }
  }]);
```